# I have a custom text field so I want to display data format like this "XXXXXXXXXX4567" in HTML Template how can we achieve this Please suggest

Tags: salesforce1-app, formula, validation-rule, html

I have a custom text field so I want to display data format like this  "XXXXXXXXXX4567" in HTML Template how can we achieve this Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

HTML templates can only display basic fields. So, you would need a formula field:

#### MaskedCustomTextField__c (Text) =

```
LPAD(CustomTextField__c,LEN(CustomTextField__c)-4,"X") &
RIGHT(CustomTextField__c,4)
```

Put the formula field into the HTML template, and you're good to go:

```
{!Account.MaskedCustomTextField__c}
```

If you use a Visualforce template, you can put it directly in to your text:

```
{!LPAD(CustomTextField__c,LEN(CustomTextField__c)-4,"X") &
RIGHT(CustomTextField__c,4)}
```